# ASP .NET MVC - DropDownList OnChange

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dom-events, onchange, dropdownlistfor

I want to hide some data when I select a value in my dropdownList.

Example :

When I choose Gender = M, I don't want to see in my Title : Mr. Only Miss or Madame.

Here is my code :

```
     @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Gender, new[] {
                           new SelectListItem() {Text = "M", Value = "M"},
                           new SelectListItem() {Text = "F", Value = "F"},
                           }, "---Choose Gender---", new { onchange = "Select();" })

     @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Title, new[] {
                           new SelectListItem() {Text = "Mister", Value = "Mr."},
                           new SelectListItem() {Text = "Madame", Value = "Mme."},
                           new SelectListItem() {Text = "Miss", Value = "Miss."}
                            }, "---Choose Title---")
```

In Javascript Section :

```
   function Select() {
        // the code.
    }
```

Comment: You should be more specific. Where is the Title that you want to modify? Is it the title of the Html page?

Comment: You should also show what you've tried so far. What you've posted so far looks like you couldn't be bothered & have asked SO to solve the problem for you.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this with the help of JQuery,

```
  function changeGender()
    {
    if($('#Gender').val()=='M')
    {
    $('#Title').html('');
    $('#Title').html('<option value="Mister">Mr.</option>');
    }
    else if($('#Gender').val()=='F')
    {
    $('#Title').html('');
    $('#Title').html('<option value="Madame">Madam</option><option value="Miss">Miss.</option>');
    }
    else
    {
    $('#Title').html('');
    }
return false;
    }
```

Hope this helps.